# Why does Wolverine still have Adamantium claws in X-Men: Days of Future Past?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine, chronology, x-men-days-of-future-past

On the future scenes of Days of Future Past Wolverine's adamantium claws can be seen (they even appear on the movie's poster). But towards the end of the The Wolverine, I remember those claws were cut by the Silver Samurai, and he even grows new bone claws after that. How come Wolverine has his adamantium claws again in Days of Future Past?

Comment: He cant regrow the adamatium. He can only regenerate his NATURAL body. If you saw X-Men origins you would see how he got the adamatium. So I think there's a movie missing between: The Wolverine and Days of Futures past.

Comment: i think wolverine (2013) happens after days of future past (2014) as we can see that wolverine is all alone and looks wild. maybe xmen got spilt or everyone died of old age

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I haven't seen **X-Men: Days of Future Past**, so I can't comment on whether this was shown in the film, but [this site](http://screenrant.com/x-men-days-future-past-rogue-wolverine-metal-claws/) does include quotes from the director, Bryan Singer, on the issue:

> That wasn’t the only tempting breadcrumb that Singer threw to Empire,
>   as part of the organization’s Days of Future Past marketing blitz.
>   Fans who’ve been paying close attention to the footage and images
>   released from the film thus far have observed that modern-day
>   Wolverine appears to have regained his Adamantium-laced claws, despite
>   the events that took place in last year’s The Wolverine; when asked by
>   Empire, Singer hinted at a possible explanation:
>
> Director Bryan Singer explains that Magneto’s ability to manipulate
>   metal might have something to do with it. The Master Of Magnetism
>   could, perhaps, “reconstitute the adamantium claws… [Wolverine] has a
>   different relationship with Magneto, and perhaps Magneto could forge
>   them.”

Comment: Ahh...so now they are going to answer every plot-hole in interviews. Why don't they cleared it in movie? That's why i hate Singer and fox because they kills continuity every time and ignores existing work for money.

Comment: The Xmen movies are all over the place from that point of view

Comment: I have to admit I assumed that the facility he lost his claws in would have the ability to give them back again given they'd been working with adamantium already.

Comment: Confirmed [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/69026/21267).

Answer (score 8):

If you watch the movie *The Wolverine* until the end then you can see that Wolverine meets Prof. Xavier and Magneto at the airport and they ask to regroup. Both these characters help Wolverine to his metal claws back (*with major help from Magneto of course, because he controls metal*) so that they can fight the Giant Mutant Destroyers in *X-Men: Days of Future past* because Wolverine has the power to heal.

Helping Wolverine to get back metal claws is not shown anywhere but it's understood when Magneto says, "What do I want? I want your help" (*in the airport scene*) and in return Magneto helps Wolverine.

Comment: I just saw that scene, and was hoping Magneto was really the key of fixing Wolverine's adamantium claws. :)

Answer (score -2):

There are different types of Adamantium. The one that wolverine has is Adamantium-Beta. Wolverine possesses Regenerative Healing powers. During his exposure to Adamantium whilst having it bonded to his skeleton, his DNA was manipulated into seeing the Beta-Adamantium as his Skeleton. He can regenerate his Skeleton very quickly, but the Adamantium takes time to grow back. So he probably just had a few weeks with normal bone claws, until the Adamantium Beta grew back.

I hope this answers your question, if not please feel free to write a reply and i will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: He _regrows_ Adamantium? Seriously?

Comment: When did you learn that? If i am not wrong then it never appeared in any X-men movie yet.

Comment: Comic logic, love it.

Answer (score -2):

Do you remember how in the x-men movies they hinted as to why his claws are adamantium?  It's because they used bone saws to inject the adamantium into his bones which would mean that just like his bone claws regrew because of his regeneration they would actually be adamantium because his bones are adamantium.  They have been making mistakes all over the series, and they are all easy to find if you watch what happens in chronological order, the only movies that have the same story line to it about the past is x-men # 1,2&3.

Comment: I can't find answer in here.

Answer (score -3):

To me this is a very easy answer. After the events of the early 1970's happened,the mutants and the humans coexisted peacefully. Wolverine,up until mid 1970's happened but the events from the late 1970's at 3 mile Island never happened. Also X Men on(circa 2001) never happened.This means Everyone had no conflicts with each other. Wolverine was the only one who was completly lost when the space-time continuum finally remerged in 2001.This means Wolverine never lost his claws in Japan.

Comment: What...??? Did you even read the question?

Answer (score -3):

Due to Logan altering the time line in DOFP, X-Men 1,2 and 3 never happened neither did The wolverine so he never lost his metal claws.

Comment: You are talking about the changed future. However, the future scenes the question is talking about still happen inside the old unchanged timeline, where *The Wolverine* happened very well.

Answer (score -3):

There probably is a movie missing where he gets his claws back, if you look in the picture i attached you can see his bodyguard being handed  box with his clause in it at the end of The wolverine.[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Do you have any evidence to support your claims?

Comment: There is no proof yet because the movie hasn't come out yet, this is just a possibility. (notice the word "probably") also i read it somewhere on the internet, but she is being handed something important, they made it too obvious even though in the background.

Answer (score -3):

1. Most likely magneto grafted the metal in his body to his claws. Remember the metal manipulation in x2 when he broke free?
2. The box being handed to the girl at the end of the wolverine is actually an original Wolverine suit she showed to him on the plane. It's in the deleted scenes. Just a tease too. It never made it to Days of Future Past.
3. Even if the metal became chemically bonded to his skeleton which allows for more metal to regenerate, they wouldn't allow that to be on screen. They tried to stray away from comic booky stuff as much as possible to create a real world explanation for everything that happens.
4. Think about it. It's an X-Men movie. As much as we love them, Havoc is still older than cyclops in the upcoming X-Men: Apocalypse movie, so what does that tell you? Deal with it!

Comment: A lot of your answer seems like mere conjecture. You bring up deleted scenes, but unless they were added back in via some kind of director's cut, they're just that: deleted and not intended to be used as canon for the story.

Comment: What does havoc has to do with it?  Did they ever made public that they will stay away from comics?