# Does Wolverine still have his adamantium claws after the change in events?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

Wolverine ends up changing history from 1973 and manages to change the outcome of the future. In the scene where Wolverine gets pulled from the bottom of the bay and onto the boat, **General Stryker** (*Mystique in disguise*) takes Wolverine from there.

Most will agree that she probably does this so Wolverine wouldn't have to suffer being taken by the real General Stryker. Does that mean that Wolverine doesn't end up in the hands of the real General Stryker at any point in time from that day and the future when he returns? If so, *wouldn't that mean that he never gets the adamantium injected into him*? This could only mean that Wolverine ends up returning to the future having only his claws of bone because he doesn't go through the adamantium procedure. Is that right or is there an alternate possibility?

Comment: Somewhat related with slightly overlapping answers: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/why-does-wolverine-still-have-adamantium-claws-in-x-men-days-of-future-past and http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/20078/questions-after-watching-x-men-days-of-future-past

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher somewhat or i will say completely covered up.

Comment: The same question was asked on the sci fi exchange: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/58319/20393

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, he still ends up with Adamantium claws (and a broken memory).

With the release of *X-Men: Apocalypse* we definitely know that **Wolverine still ends up with Adamantium claws** even in the changed timeline.

It is true that it was actually Mystique who picked him up from the river at the end of *Days of Future Past* and he thus had a much lower chance to end up with Stryker. However, during the events of *Apocalypse*, which are set 10 years later in 1983 in the already changed timeline, some of the (not yet) X-Men end up in a secret facility of Stryker's. There they eventually come across a cage that contains a so-called **"Weapon X", which turns out to be noone else than Wolverine himself, full with metal claws and an apparently heavily damaged memory**.

It is still unclear how he ended up with Stryker after he was recovered by Mystique, but there is no doubt that he did and that this facility (apparently in a snowy area) is probably the exact facility at Alkali Lake where Logan returns to in *X2*. And seeing his deranged memory and animal-like behaviour, his actual **backstory as depicted in the first few *X-Men* films does't really seem to have changed much**.

And while the filmmakers said that [the events of *X-Men: The Last Stand* and *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* are largely eradicated from continuity](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49130/49), it is still left unclear how much of the first two *X-Men* films stays intact. In an [interview with Collider](http://collider.com/x-men-apocalypse-new-timeline-explained-bryan-singer/) directors/producers Bryan Singer and Simon Kinberg explain that while the specific events are largely open now, there is nothing that prevents them from panning out similar to how they did in the existing films either. And in [this CinemaBlend article](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-X-Men-Screenwriter-Resolves-Wolverine-Mystery-From-End-Days-Future-Past-131267.html) **Simon Kinberg explicitly said that Wolverine's fate as "Weapon X" stays largely the same** due to a certain immutability of the timeline with respect to specific key events (call it "destiny", if you want):

> Borrowing a bit of scientific theory and dialogue from the last *X-Men* movie, Kinberg explained that the idea is that Wolverine was always going to end up in the Weapon X program despite all of the events that changed in his life due to time-travel antics. Said Kinberg,
>
> > One of the things we talk about in *Days of Future Past* - there’s a scene where Hank/Beast talks about the immutability of time. Basically, you can change the way the future goes, but it finds its way back. So while we don’t show how, it found its way back to Wolverine being part of Weapon X and under the thumb of Stryker, that’s the idea.

Comment: To add to this ( i think it's the best answer ) - would be that despite the damaged memory - he still finally gets all those from the previous timeline back in the future (See the ending of Days of Future Past when he sees Xavier in the school)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think so because;

1. the writers at Marvel (presumably) understand how time travel works. Meaning if Wolverine wasn't saved by Stryker in the movie and ends up not having Adamantium claws that would mean that all of the Wolverine movies as well as the first three X Men movies have an inconsistency.
2. He could meet Stryker again in the future/past(?) which would mean he would get the claws.
3. Hopefully it will be explained in the next movie (I haven't read the comics).

Comment: Your first two reasons sound like the first sentence should actually read *"would"* instead of *"wouldn't"*, otherwise there would seem to be a rhetorical inconsistency. And as to 1), why should those movies have an inconsistency, they didn't even happen in that timeline at all, so there particular plot is completely irrelevant, if inconsistent or not (remember how *Jean* and *Scott* are alive, too)?

Answer (score -2):

This probably wouldn't change the continuity of wolverine's past at all as I believe Mystique only uses the disguise to order some soldiers to fish his body out of the river.

Her reasoning for this could be that she realizes how important wolverine is in the possible future or far more likely she did it as a favor called in by xavier.