# Which of Deadpool's origin is actual?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, x-men-origins-wolverine

I have limited knowledge of Marvel Comics.
As per *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, William Stryker created Deadpool (Weapon XI).
Where as in the recently released *Deadpool*, Ajax did induce mutations in him and he claims the name Deadpool.

What is the actual timeline? Did Wade Wilson meet Stryker first before becoming Deadpool; If no, then how did he cure his face? If yes, then was he always a good swordsman?

Comment: Closely related: [Where does Deadpool fall in the X-men timeline?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47738/where-does-deadpool-fall-in-the-x-men-timeline)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After [X-Men: Days of Future Past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past) and all that time travelling weirdness happens inside it, [X-Men Origins: Wolverine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine) and [X3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_The_Last_Stand) are considered non canon. Below is the producer's interview

So the actual origin of Deadpool is what we have seen in the Deadpool film. He no longer met Stryker and his mouth wasn't sewed shut. And Deadpool's transformation happens way way after the original transformation from X-Men Origins.

Comment: Nothing in that interview implies that X1 or X2 are still canon.

Comment: @cde So we can interpret  they are canon till they say it otherwise.

Comment: The timelines changes in DOFP and Apocalypse make that impossible. There is no way that they did.

Comment: @cde Yes it's changed but they didn't reach to point of X-men 1 so we can't be sure, till then it's all speculation till we have God's word. That's why i only mentioned about the 2 films only which are surely non-canon. To me more problem is The wolverine, how can be it's canon when it's based on X-men 3 which is non canon.

Comment: http://collider.com/x-men-apocalypse-new-timeline-explained-bryan-singer/

Comment: @cde for this answer, this is not necessary to explicitly mention about X-men 1 and 2 but I did used your link for my other answer ;).

Comment: What about now, after DP2? :)