# What happened to Magneto after the past changed in X Men Days of Future Past?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In **X Men Days of Future Past**, After the history was changed, Logan wakes up and we see that everyone is there, including Charles, Jean, Scott, Storm, and Beast. However, Magneto was not there. He was also with Charles and remaining X Men when they went to China to seek help of Kitty.

I am curious to know what happened to Magneto in the end when past was changed?

Comment: Well, it seems we'll soon find out part of it in the new film. Everything else we have absolutely no chance of knowing.

Comment: It may, may be explained in Apocalypse.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, we'll see, but i do not think it will be there in X Men Apocalypse because, according to wikipedia, this movie will focus on event took place in 80's.

Comment: @AJ Then where do you think this information will be then?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, well I do not know. I am asking about the Magneto in 2022, not about the 83's. Moreover, If there is any reference about this in Upcoming movie, we'll know this week.

Comment: Rumor has it he will be in the savage lands.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I just watched the movie X Men Apocalypse and there was no such reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magneto's disappearance in the new future clearly suggests that he didn't come together with Professor X. And it's reason is clear because there is no risk of Sentinels anymore.

So we can conclude any number of theories about it, like he is still planning something bad, or retired from his villain work or died or anything you can ever think of. But we don't know what happened because now the old trilogy is no more canon, as discussed in [one of my own answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/52736/1190).

So we only know what happens till X-Men Apocalypse, rest is uncertain. As per X-Men Apocalypse, the latest status of the character is:

> Magneto helps rebuilding the X-Mansion with Jean Gray and then goes on his separate ways.