# Is Wade Wilson in X-Men Origins: Wolverine and Deadpool same person?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, the-wolverine, x-men-origins-wolverine

**I haven't seen Deadpool 2 so No Spoilers.**

Just a thing came to my mind about the Two mercenaries,

*Deadpool* from the movie **Deadpool** (a.k.a **Wade Wilson**) and *Weapon X* (a.k.a **Wade Wilson**) from the movie **X-Men Origins: Wolverine**.

Is there any relation between them?

If yes, What is the chronological order of these two films?

If Wolverine occurs first then the Wade Wilson or weapon X is probably dead.

If Deadpool occurs first then how come Wade Wilson get rid of that scarred body?

There is one similarity I reckon, those katanas and the ability to dodge the bullets.

Comment: Already covered here [Which of Deadpool's origin is actual?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49128/which-of-deadpools-origin-is-actual)

Comment: Can't be answered without spoilers for Deadpool 2, it was touched upon in Deadpool 2 so you can watch it to get the answer.

Comment: Then I will come back after watching Deadpool 2

Comment: Okay. Now I know about the Deadpool. But the Juggernaut in the Deadpool 2 is large and gigantic as compared to X-men series.