# Why does Wolverine have metal claws in X-men Apocalypse?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-apocalypse

[The latest trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jer8XjMrUB4) shows Wolverine's claws at the end, but according to what I'd think is the new continuity after Days of Future Past, he should no longer have adamantium, is there an explanation for this?

[image: Claws]

Comment: Potentially the same explanation as http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19701/why-does-wolverine-still-have-adamantium-claws-in-x-men-days-of-future-past Even if the explanation is different, the explanation may come in the film itself, so it's possible that there's no way to answer this at this time.

Answer (score 6):

The "new" continuity that exists after *Days of Future Past* isn't actually clear. We know that the movies *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* and *X-Men 3: The Final Stand* are no longer canon, but that doesn't *necessarily* mean that those events didn't happen in some form or another.

In particular, note that all of the remaining X-Men films are still canon, so all of those things supposedly still happened. That includes, for example, *X-Men* where Wolverine's adamantium bones are a significant plot element. So obviously, he must have gotten them somewhere. Perhaps we'll learn where in the next movie, or perhaps in the upcoming solo movie.

At the end of *Days of Future Past* in the past timeline, when Logan's future mind leaves his past body, we see him being retrieved from the river by Mystique, disguised as William Stryker. [According to the director](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/days-future-past-secrets-explained/), this is supposed to represent Mystique saving mutants from their original fates, but in truth we have no idea what happened to him after that point.

Also, note that the things that happened in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* prior to 1973 should also "still have happened", just perhaps not as they were shown in *Origins*. But Wolverine first met Stryker and joined Weapon X either during or shortly after the Vietnam War, which effectively ended in 1973 as well. It's never explained why Logan isn't *in* Vietnam during *Days of Future Past*, unfortunately, but it's not unreasonable to assume that Stryker still has his sights set on Wolverine -- which would explain why Mystique was impersonating Stryker in the end scene -- and he will still end up giving him the adamantium sometime between the 1970s and the 1980s.

Comment: "It's never explained why Logan isn't in Vietnam" - the setting is that the war has just ended. You see soldiers demobilising near the beginning and much of the action is set at the victory conference.

Comment: except in _Wolverine_ I'm pretty sure as soon as the war ended Stryker found him there, not in the US.

Comment: There's a reason they retconned *Wolverine* - it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

## Because Stryker just implanted the adamantium in him.

In X2 and X-Men Origins we learn all about how Stryker implanted the adamantium in Wolverine at Alkali Lake some time in Wolverine's past. This scene in X-Men: Apocalypse, where Stryker attempts to imprison the other mutants at Alkali Lake represents that event in the altered timeline.

Answer (score -3):

The Wolverine happened before & was the lead in to Days Of Future Past, so when DOFP started he should have no claws, but he does from the 1st time we see them early on

Magnetto is not a scientist, he doesn't know how to graft metal, only move it...
even if in incredible ways. So we can eliminate that theory.(I doubt Wolvie would have wantn't them back anyway. It's extremely painful, & unnatural. They probably hurt more to extract too.)

Nor does it have anything to do with changing the past, cause he had them early on in D.O.F.P.

And, NO, adamantium doesn't regenerant. It's inorganic.

Thus Wolverine probably has adamantium claws, because Bryan Singer was saying "fU" to James Mangold. Taking away his iconic claws is almost a sin to fans. Different directors have different visions. (Even Logan's dogs tags were different in different movies, thus Gavin Hood has different ideas of what time Logan went into the military than Bryan Singer.)

I partially agree with that premise. Lossing one set of claws was OK, but two was retarded. Wolverine is not dumb, so he wouldn't extract his claws knowing the giant-silver samurai-cyborg thing would want that. Doing so is just saying Logan is a clueless idiot, and his actions in all the movies prior prove otherwise.

In a way, they are saying The Wolverine never happened in the same reality as any of the other films. Truth be told it was the worst in a great series. (Losing the claws was not the only issue I have with it either.)